# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name returns null when website folder moved

Tags: c#, iis

While reading IIS help I realized it might be better to move my web site from a folder under `"My Documents"` to `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\`, but when I do this my website throws an error, `"Invalid UserId"`, which I traced to the fact that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is returning `null`. How could moving my website files cause this ?

I tried adding my userid as well as `MachineName\NETWORK SERVICE and MachineName\ASPNET` to the new folder, but that didn't' help.

The original path which works: `C:\Documents and Settings\Userid\Budget`
The new path (throws error): `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Budget`

I used windows explorer to select all the files in the original folder, I then copied and pasted them to the new folder.
The code that uses `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is in `Default.aspx.cs` which is the first page to load. Here is the entire line of code:

```
public User CURRENT_USER = AppCode.BusinessLayer.Security.User.GetUserById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

It's calling User.cs which contains `GetUserById`. `GetUserById` examines the argument and checks for nulls, then throws the `"Invalid UserId"` error.

7/29/2014 2:00 PM Central:

We obtained this website from another institution who did all the coding. They tell me it was set up to use SQL Server authentication. I set our SQL Server instance to use mixed mode which is the only other option besides windows authentication. The connection strings have the userId and pw hard coded, and I believe they are set up to use SQL Server authentication.

I am not the only person who will be using this website, I am just trying to get it up and running. Eventually there will be a few instances, Development, Production, etc.

7/29/2014 3:06 PM C:

I can't answer my own question yet due to stackoverflow constraints, so I'll answer it here:

```
          THE FIX:
```

I needed to disable anonymous access in IIS.

Thanks

Comment: What type of authentication are you using in your website? Are you the only one who will be using it?

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong authentication.